# Bootstrap 3.3 shows double scrollbars on modals

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I am working with Bootstrap 3.3.1 modals and it was working perfectly until yesterday.

I'm using some modal windows on my page.
One of those modals is more long than the page. In a normal time, Bootstrap transparently hides the body's scrollbar and creates a scrollbar on the overlay. When the user scrolls on the modal, it is stopped when it reach the end. And the body doesn't moves at all.

But, yesterday, I was working on my modals and now it is completely buggy. I have no idea of the thing I introduced that destructs my modals.

First, Bootstrap applies an offset of 15px on the body, even on the small modals that have a height inferior to the screen height.
The content is uselessly shifted.
Second, the body keeps its scrollbar when a modal is displayed. And the overlay also have its scrollbar. So, I have an hideous double scrollbar on my page, and when the user scrolls at the end of the modal, the body scrolls too.

Also, *sometimes* (yes), the overlay is buggy and it scrolls with the body (so I can see the body without overlay at the bottom of the page).

I have no idea of what can cause this problem since it was working before.

**Edit:** Here is my code : http://pastebin.com/ePAcjri8. The position of the modals in the page has no effects on this bug (just after `<body>`, juste before `</body>`, etc).
I fill the modal content via Ajax when shown.
On JavaScript side, I'm just using `.modal('show')` then `.html(html)` to fill them.

Comment: Update to v3.3.2. Post your full code.

Comment: Just posted my code into the original post.
I can't upgrade beacause I use an "outdated" theme of Bootswatch. But a rapid switch to the original Bootstrap 3.3.2 doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.
I think this issue can be caused by a lot of different reasons (see topics about this problem on the Internet, but alot have been fixed in Bootstrap releases), but in my case, I just had to remove this in my CSS:

```
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Hiding the `x` or `y` overflow in `<html>` can cause the apparition of the double scrollbar.